# To delete the last n records where n is the number of list items ..

Tags: visual-studio

Please try to help me
I've been working on my college project and I need a visual basic 6.0 program coding to ' delete the last n records of the access table where n is the number of items in a list ' with the same button ...

Comment: Whats' been attempted so far?

Comment: I used for loop to check the listcount and tried  recordset.movelast and recordset.delete to delete for each value .... That is

Comment: private sub command1_ click()
dim i as integer
i=0
for i=0 to list1.listcount-1
rs. movelast
rs.delete
i=i+1
next
end sub